# How do I change my default alarm clock app?

Tags: applications, 7.0-nougat, alarm

So trying to get it so I can say "ok Google, set alarm x".  But it defaults to the basic alarm on my phone which is not a good alarm clock.  Looking through settings, apps, there seems to be a way to switch the default program for everything except alarm clocks.
Thank you

Comment: Try this - go to settings > apps and Disable the default alarm clock. Now maybe it will open the clock you installed !

Comment: Great idea. Not working out.  The default alarm is tied to the clock app.  Which doesn't seem to change anything after I disable it.

Answer (score 6):

Say: "Okay Google, set a timer".
When it prompts you for the duration, there will be an option somewhere on the screen where you can click and select a different timer app.

Comment: This worked really well on Mi UI 10 with Google Voice

Comment: Worked on my Galaxy S10!  I was able to replace the Samsung clock app with the Google clock app.

Comment: Worked on Huawei P30 Pro!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the problem solved itself, or if it was something I did. Instead of OK Google set alarm, I did OK Google "specific alarm app" "time" , and it now defaults without having to specify the app anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I use Alarm Clock Plus and was having the same problem with the requested alarms defaulting to the system's clock app.  Using Joshh's answer, I said "OK Google Alarm Clock Plus set alarm for 9am".  Once Google used Alarm Clock Plus, it became the default.

Answer (score 1):

I installed alarm clock plus, and did as above  "OK Google Alarm Clock Plus set alarm for 9am". This changed the default alarm clock, when I deleted the alarm clock plus app it prompted me for a new default app the next time I said "set alarm 6am"  This allowed me to resolve another calendar app that was stealing system clock alarms.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I changed the default app. Hope it works for you :

A) "ok Google, set  alarm"
B) the following screen appeared
X) tap on the icon and change the app to your desired alarm app (I use any.do as it has a snooze function)

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Google Assistant mode, when you say "ok Google set alarm", it will type your words as you speak, and then vocally respond, typing its words as it speaks, in a facsimile of a text messenger.  An icon for the clock app it's currently using should appear beneath Google's response as she asks you when you would like to set it for.  If you click on this, it will drop down a menu of options for which clock app you'd like to use, and then it will use this as your default alarm clock later on.  I believe you may also be able to say "view alarms".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replace the default app for timers:

- Open Assistant.
- Click the icon at bottom left that goes to some assistant home page.
- Find the set timer action in the list at the top. It opens a card to edit the timer details.
- On that card, click the timely icon and select the default clock from the list.